# Бот не реагирует на кнопки в дискорде python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот код

```
async def test(ctx):
 await ctx.send(
 embed=discord.Embed(title='Помощник прибыл!',
                     description='Выбери что тебе нужно',
                     colour=discord.Color(0x0ffff)),
 components=[
     #первая линия
     [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Модерация'),
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label='Развлечения')],
     #вторая линия
     [Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label='Наш дискорд сервер!', url="https://discord.gg/buKtm6xYSR"),
      Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='Наш сайт')]
 ]
)
 response = await bot.await_for("button_click")
 if response.channel == ctx.channel:
     if response.component.label == "Наш сайт":
         await response.respond(content= "Наш сайт")
     else:
         await response.respond(
             embed=discord.Embed(title="Сайт в разработке"),
             components=[
                  Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Дискорд сервер", url="https://discord.gg/buKtm6xYSR")
             ]
         )
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, кнопки уже не так делаются. Вот рабочий пример - [ТЫК](https://vk.com/@helish88-primer-knopochek-s-pomoschu-discordpy-20)

Comment: Ты какую библиотеку используешь?

Answer (score 0):

Данный способ создания устарел. Лучше для кнопок использовать библиотеку pycord.

**Пример создания кнопок:**

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot() # Create a bot object

# Create a class called MyView that subclasses discord.ui.View
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    # Create a button with the label " Click me!" with color Blurple
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="")
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        # Send a message when the button is clicked
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!") 

@bot.slash_command() # Create a slash command
async def button(ctx):
    # Send a message with our View class that contains the button
    await ctx.respond("This is a button!", view=MyView())

bot.run("TOKEN") # Run the bot
```

[Документация pycord buttons](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/ui-components/buttons/)